# how to perform MySQL smart text search in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, soundex

I am trying to search for a shop name in one of MySQL table, the table has a field called fullname. As of now I am using the SOUNDS LIKE method of MySQL however here's an example that failed:

Say I have the string Banana's Shop. Then using SOUNDS LIKE with query of 'nana' or 'bananas' won't give me the result. Here's my current query:

```
SELECT `fullName` FROM `shop` WHERE `fullName` SOUNDS LIKE 'nana';
```

is there a better way to do simple search like this in MySQL that is smarter so that typo's would also still match?

Answer (score 0):

The ancient and slightly honorable SOUNDEX algorithm used by `SOUNDS LIKE` doesn't handle suffix sounds.  That is, `nana` doesn't, and can't, match `banana`. `banani` will match `banana`, however.

Two utterances don't necessarily sound alike unless they have the same number of syllables.  It's good for matching stuff like surnames: Smith, Schmitt, and Schmidt all have the same SOUNDEX value.

Calling SOUNDEX 'smart text search' is an exaggeration. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

You might consider MySQL FULLTEXT search, which you can look up.  This does a certain amount of phrase matching.  That is, if you had "banana shop" and "banana slug" in your column, the word "banana" would have a shot at matching both those values.

Be careful with FULLTEXT. It works counterintuitively when you have less than about a couple of hundred rows in the table you're searching.

But that's not a typo-friendly word matcher. What you're asking isn't really easy.

You could consider the Levenshtein algorithm (which you can look up). But it's a hairball to get working properly.

Comment: rephrased the question a bit

Comment: added some info to answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, have you had experience with elastic search or lucene?